# What web application firewall do you use? What should I use?

Tags: firewall, reverse-proxy, mod-security, web-application-firewall, application-firewall

What web application firewall do you use?  I'm primarily interested in something I can deploy on the perimeter that can protect multiple Apache and IIS servers, but I'd like to hear all answers.  Tell me a little bit about how many servers it protects, what kind of load, performance, price.  Basically anything you want to share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having said I have no experience in using [Mod Security](http://www.modsecurity.org/), I like to share the following [review](http://blog.supportpro.com/2009/08/mod_security-intro/):

> ModSecurity is an open source web
>   application firewall (WAF) engine for
>   Apache that is developed by
>   Trustwave's SpiderLabs. It has a
>   robust event-based programming
>   language which provides protection
>   from a range of attacks against web
>   applications and allows for HTTP
>   traffic monitoring, logging and
>   real-time analysis. With over 10,000
>   deployments world-wide, ModSecurity is
>   the most widely deployed WAF in
>   existence.
>
> It operates embedded into the web
>   server, acting as a powerful umbrella
>   – shielding applications from attacks.
>   ModSecurity supports both branches of
>   the Apache web server.
>
> The module filters, and optionally
>   rejects, incoming requests based on a
>   number of different criteria like CGI
>   variables, HTTP headers, environment
>   variables, and even individual script
>   parameters. mod_security can also
>   create an audit log, storing full
>   request details in a separate file,
>   including POST payloads (the audit
>   feature can be turned on or off on a
>   per-server or per-directory basis).
>
> **Advantage**
>
> The advantage of mod_security is
>   “security”.
>
> 1. No network side configuration
> 2. Easy management.
> 3. Free as in Beer
> 4. HTTP intrusion detection and prevention
>
> **Disadvantages**
>
> 1. You have to become a security expert
> 2. You have to become a protocol expert.
> 3. The configuration must be done manually.
> 4. Performance degradation

Answer (score 0):

The Barracuda Web Application Firewall provides a good browser based management/configuration UI which can be setup by most admins which are comfortable setting up IIS or Apache, with just reading their documentation.  I know it works with IIS and Apache servers as I've used it with both, and it should work with any server which follows the HTTP/HTTPS standards. We have it deployed as a VM, but you can also buy it as an appliance, or their are even cloud based deployment models.  For us, it defends 23 servers hitting only about 20% of it's CPU capacity during our current peaks. It add only single digit ms to the latency.

The main advantage I see compared to Imperva's product is:

1. Quicker to configure
2. Less likely to need to hire vendors professional services, as most knowledable web server admins with just a little reading of the product documentation can configure it, while with Imperva, a greater percentage of people will need to hire their professional services to configure it.

Sorry, can't compare to mod_security as I've never used it.